# Toggle text to match multiple spans

Tags: jquery, html, text

I have a span with the class "toggle" in two different tables. I have some jQuery code that toggles the spans text back and forth and that works great, but what I'm struggling with, is how to get both spans to toggle at the same time if one is clicked, so their text matches each other.

I've tried using `span[class='toggle']` as the onclick object hoping that would select both of them and run the code, but that didn't work

```
$("span[class='toggle']").on("click", function() {
    var oldText = $(this).text();
    var newText = $(this).data('text');
    $(this).text(newText).data('text', oldText);
});
```

[Here's a fiddle to demo:](https://jsfiddle.net/rscott29/n4ub0bcj/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add `each()` loop inside click callback function so that you execute your code for each input no matter what input is clicked. Note that context of `$(this)`  is current element in loop not clicked element [**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/Lg0wyt9u/1433/)

```
$("span[class='toggle']").on("click", function() {
  $("span[class='toggle']").each(function() {
    var oldText = $(this).text();
    var newText = $(this).data('text');
    $(this).text(newText).data('text', oldText);
  })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming I have understood you and you want both to switch to the **same value**

replace : 
  ***$(this).text(newText).data('text',oldText);***

with:

***$("span[class='toggle']").text(newText).data('text',oldText);***

This will update both of the spans to the new text upon clicking either of them.

Answer (score 1):

Easy.

You just need to replace `$(this)` by `$("span[class='toggle']")`.

When you are on your "on click" function. You call $(this) which is the element clicked. That's why your text change only in one *span*.

**JS**

```
$("span[class='toggle']").on("click",function () {
    var oldText = $(this).text();
    var newText = $(this).data('text');
    $("span[class='toggle']").text(newText).data('text',oldText);
});
```

Here's a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/czbo11sx/).

Answer (score 1):

Here is working one with little modification. `$(this).text(newText).data('text', oldText);` in this you're using `this` which refer to currently `click` `span` class text.

```js
$("span[class='toggle']").on("click",function () {
    oldTxt = $(this).text();
    newTxt = $(this).data('text');
    console.log(oldTxt+" "+newTxt);
    $("span[class='toggle']").text(newTxt).data('text', oldTxt);
 });
```

```css
span {
    color: #18c;
    cursor: pointer;
}
span:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="table1">
<span class="toggle" data-text="Analysis View">Reports View</span>
</div>
<div id="table2">
<span class="toggle" data-text="Analysis View">Reports View</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks very much!